# Detecting center and area of shapes in an image

Tags: graphics, gd

[image: Dotted image]

I am working with GD library, and I'm looking for a way to detect the nearest pixel to the middle center of shapes, as well as total area used by each shape in a monochromic black-and-white image.

I'm having difficulty coming up with an efficient algorithm to do this. If you have done something similar to this in the past, I'd be grateful for any solution that would help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the binary image library

Essentially, Otsu threshold to separate out foreground from background, then label connected components. That particular image looks very clean but you might need morph ops to clean it up a bit and get rid of small holes and other artifacts.

Then you have area trivially (count pixels in component) or almost as trivially (use the weighted area function that penalises edge pixels). Centre is just mean.

http://malcolmmclean.github.io/binaryimagelibrary/

Answer (score 1):

@MalcolmMcLean is right but there are remaining difficulties (if you are after maximum accuracy).

If you threshold with Otsu, there are a few pairs of "kissing" dots which will form a single blob using connected component analysis.

In addition, Otsu threshoding will discard some of the partially filled edge pixels so that the weighted averages will be inaccurate. A cure would be to increase the threshold (up to 254 is possible), but that worsens the problem of the kissing dots.

A workaround is to keep a low threshold and dilate the blobs individually to obtain suitable masks that cover all edge pixels. Even so, slight inaccuracies will result in the vicinity of the kissings.

Blob splitting by the watershed transform is also possible but more care is required to handle the common pixels. I doubt that a prefect solution is possible.

---

An alternative is the use of subpixel edge detection and least-squares circle fitting (after blob detection with a very low threshold to separate the dots). By avoiding the edge pixels common to two circles, you can probably achieve excellent results.